# I keep on getting pubsepc.yaml error when running flutter?

Tags: sdk

```
name: churro
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
camera: ^0.10.0+4
story_view: ^0.14.0
flutter:
    sdk: flutter


cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

  flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
      - assets/images/
```

[churro] flutter pub get
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Unexpected child "sdk" found under "flutter".
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your indentation being off. The following should resolve your issue:

```yaml
name: churro
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  camera: ^0.10.0+4
  story_view: ^0.14.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```